# CloudFormation template installs but no indication of when script finishes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following CloudFormation script which sets up all the infrastructure correctly. When I get a CREATE_COMPLETE message from CloudFormation, the EC2 is accessible via SSH but the applications have not installed. If I wait 3 minutes, they then appear.

Is there any way to make CloudFormation wait until all the meta data has been installed (git and htop)?

Script below:

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "My first CloudFormation template",

"Resources": {
    "WebServerInstance": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-abeb9e91",
            "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
            "KeyName": "test-key-pair",
            "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "WebServerSecurityGroup"} ],
            "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": { "Fn::Join":["", [
                    "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
                    "apt-get update\n",
                    "apt-get -y install python-setuptools\n",
                    "mkdir aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest\n",
                    "curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz | tar xz -C aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest --strip-components 1\n",
                    "easy_install aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest\n",
                    "sudo /usr/local/bin/cfn-init --stack ", { "Ref":"AWS::StackName" }, " --resource WebServerInstance", " --region ", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
                    "\n",
                    "/usr/local/bin/cfn-signal --exit-code $?"
                ]]}
            }
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                "config": {
                    "packages": {
                        "apt": {
                            "htop": [],
                            "git": []
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CreationPolicy Attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html#deployment-walkthrough-cfn-signal) is what you need.